# Does Azure ServiceBus QueueClient.OnMessage execute on a different thread

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

Does the QueueClient.OnMessage method always execute the callback parameter on a different thread?

I assume that if MaxConcurrentCalls is set to 10 then the queueClient would spin up a maximum of 10 threads to process the messages in parallel. Does a new thread get created if you pass in a MaxConcurrentConnection value of 1 or does it execute back on the current thread?

My actual problem:
Within a Worker Role I would like to handle multiple queues but have them all process concurrently. E.g.

```cs
        _queueClient1.OnMessage(x =>
        {
            // Do something
        }, new OnMessageOptions { MaxConcurrentCalls = 1});

        _queueClient2.OnMessage(x =>
        {
            // Do something
        }, new OnMessageOptions { MaxConcurrentCalls = 1 });

        _queueClient3.OnMessage(x =>
        {
            // Do something
        }, new OnMessageOptions { MaxConcurrentCalls = 1 });

        _queueClient4.OnMessage(x =>
        {
            // Do something
        }, new OnMessageOptions { MaxConcurrentCalls = 1 });
```

Would this result in each callback being executed in parallel so that the _queueClient4 callback isn't waiting for _queueClient2 to finish before it can execute?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you register a callback with `OnMessage` it is called on a different thread. If you set `MaxConcurrentCalls` to say 10, then we will create 10 threads for 10 messages and callback all of these for each message concurrently. You can do this across Queues too as you show above but of course there is no synchronization or ordering done between each individual callback processing.

When we invoke the callback on a new thread, then it is synchronous for that particular execution/message in that until the method completes or an exception is thrown, the message processing is not completed. If `MaxConcurrentCalls` is 0 then only a single thread will be processed for each of the callback registered. However when you have different QueueClient instances you can register different callbacks to them or the same callback with different concurrent counts etc.

Comment: Thanks Abhishek, just to clarify: If I call OnMessage with MaxConcurrentCalls set to 10 then 10 threads are spun up immediately which wait until messages are available on the queue. Then each thread independently processes a message; each thread is unavailable to process any other messages until it's callback returns?

Comment: The threads are only spun up when there are messages to process. There is only a single pending Receive call and that invokes the callbacks concurrently on different threads for received messages till the MaxConcurrentCalls count is reached.

Comment: FWIW - Reflecting into the code, the default value for this is 1, so by default it appears that the OnMessage pattern will only run on a single thread at a time.

Comment: @AbhishekLal is this concurrency logic any different for Messages that are part of a session? Also, above you mention this can be done across queues, with the caveat that there is no sync/ordering across individual callbacks: presumably that caveat applies to a single QueueClient instance with 10 MaxConcurrentCalls? (ie: MaxConcurrentCalls effectively breaks FIFO *guarantee* because ThreadPool handling?)

Comment: But how to gracefull shutdown/stop a message pump!?